# Scala: recursive search avoiding cycles

Tags: scala, search, recursion

How can I write a recursive search that I avoid cycles.

My class is this:

```
class Component(var name: String, var number: Int, var subComponent: Set[Component])
```

Now I need a way to check whether a component is contained within its subcomponent or between subcomponent of its subcomponent and so on.Avoiding possible cycles caused by other Component.

My method of recursive search must have the following signature,
where subC is the Set [component] of comp.

```
def content (comp: Component, subC: Set[Component]) : Boolean = {
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question, if your signature _must_ be that.  In this case, here's a handy tip.  Write an algorithm for recursive search.  Then, only recurse after you hit a new element.  How do you tell if it's new?  Why, if it's not in your set--as soon as you see something, add it!  (Bonus points: keep the entire history, not just the history along your current recursive path, so you avoid traversing the same element more than once, as well as cycles.)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to define an inner function with a `visited` accumulator.

```
def content (comp: Component, subC: Set[Component]) : Boolean = {
    def contained(comp: Component, subC: Set[Component], visited: Set[Component]): Boolean = {
        // over time (recursion) add components to visited
        // you can then use 
        //    visited contains comp
        // to check existence and 
        //    visited diff subC
        // to get the unvisited components

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to implement this is to keep a set of visited components. This can be defined as a method inside your method. The method will do the recursion. It will take the visited set as an extra argument and will be initiated with an empty set.